# Checking to see if sample average weight is statistically larger than the standard weight?

Tags: statistics

For the fallowing question, we need to assume that the sample standard deviation is 16. We need to check to see if the sample average weight of **177** is statistically larger than the standard weight of **170**. We are asked to you the usual 5 step procedure.

Question:
The following weights were obtained from a randomly selected sample of 20-year-old, 6-foot-1 inch males from Minnesota. This sample of **25** males had a mean weight of **177** lb. Based on this sample, are Minnesota males heavier than males in general? The mean weight of all US males (6'1'') is **170**lb, and the population **standard deviation is 16**. Assume a normal distribution. Use alpha= 0.05.

So, our n= 25, sd= 16, and y^bar= 177 (?)

I know it most likely seems a very easy t-test, however, I would appreciate your help. 
I have an issue organizing the steps of this problem, and starting to solve this problem: 
is Ho=177 and Ha not = 177?

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: The claim you are testing is "Minnesota males [are] heavier than males in general". How would you write that as a hypothesis?

Comment: Hypothesis would be: Minnesota males are the same weight as the males in general. So, Ho: μ = 170 (?) and then Ha: μ > 170 (?)

Comment: You definitely need $\mu > 170$ as your claim, since there's no other way to express "weighs more" than to use "more". Your textbook conventions will determine whether the other hypothesis is $=170$ or $\leq 170$.

Comment: @tabstop: so wait, the Ho would be, Ho: μ=170lb; the average weight of men is 170. ?

Comment: @tabstop: I just edited my post. Does my work looks correct? thank you!